# Given an M x N matrix, is there a way to produce an orthogonal set of N vectors of length M, where M < N?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization would only use the first M vectors to generate a basis of size M x M.

Comment: My question is: given an M x N matrix, is there a way to produce an orthogonal set of  N vectors of  length M, where M < N

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A set of orthogonal vectors is linearly independent.  Think about a basis for the space.

Comment: For this statement to be correct, you need to insert *nonzero*.